# cURL <- feature

Tags: command-line, curl

```
$ cat file | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us
```

So the output of `echo` gets passed as a POST parameter to cURL. Is this a cURL specific feature?

Comment: You can use `curl -F 'sprunge=<file' http://sprunge.us` instead.

Answer (score 8):

`-` is commonly used to represent standard input and `<` is commonly used to
represent redirection from a file. I believe those syntaxes come from early
shells. Together, they imply taking in standard input and sending/redirecting
it elsewhere. The syntax is almost natural.

Looking at the cURL [revision history](http://curl.haxx.se/dev/source.html),
the `<` syntax was added to cURL in mid-2000. The revision that added this
feature is available as Git commit `5b7a5046e6`.

From the changelog,

```
Torsten Foertsch <torsten.foertsch at gmx.net> brought a set of fixes for
the rfc1867 form posts. He introduced 'name=<file' which brings a means to
suuply very large text chunks read from the given file name. It differs from
'name=@file' in the way that this latter thing is marked in the uploaded
contents as a file upload, while the first is just text (as in a input or
textarea field). Torsten also corrected a bug that would happen if you used
%s or similar in a -F file name.
```

There is no mention of the inspiration or origin of this feature.

The `@-` syntax was present in cURL in the earliest version of the source I
could find. From the first revision in late 1999,

```
/* postfield data */
if('@' == *nextarg) {
  /* the data begins with a '@' letter, it means that a file name
     or - (stdin) follows */
  FILE *file;
  nextarg++; /* pass the @ */
```

It's difficult to determine if it is cURL-specific. The syntax is common and
natural. The cURL feature with which it is associated is a base feature of
cURL. Tools similar to cURL are likely to implement some form if it.

---

The original question asked about

```
$ echo foo | curl -d 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us
```

Here was my answer:

I do not believe that is a feature of cURL.

```
$ # Terminal A
$ curl --version
curl 7.31.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.31.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
$
$ echo foo | curl -d 'sprunge=<-' localhost:2222

$ # Terminal B
$ nc -l 2222
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.31.0
Host: localhost:2222
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

sprunge=<-
```

I couldn't find any mention of this feature in the cURL documentation. There is a similar feature though.

> If  you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to
>   read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin.  The
>   contents of the file must already be URL-encoded. Multiple files can also be
>   specified. Posting data from a file named 'foobar' would thus be done with
>   --data @foobar.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy the exact output. I ran it with the word `test` but tried to modify it to reflect the question. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Yeah I could tell you were refining the answer, just pointing that stuff out. I liked your idea in using `nc` to test this. I always forget about little `nc`.

Comment: It's in my man page. Look for `-d`. I hope you don't mind, I didn't understand what the "sprunge=<-" was until I saw your answer and realized it was data being sent in the POST.

Comment: @slm: Thanks for pointing things out. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, wrong command.

Comment: @WearetheWorld: I have adapted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Spying on curl with socat

The updated question regarding this command:

```
$ cat file | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us
```

Is doing several things. Using `socat` we can spy on the request like so in one terminal:

```
$ socat - TCP4-LISTEN:2222,fork | grep -E 'Content-Disp|msg'
```

Now in a second terminal we'll use your `curl` command to connect to our `socat` daemon. For the `cat file` we're going to use this as our sample file:

```
$ cat hello.txt
msg: hello curl
```

And when we `curl`:

```
$ cat ~/hello.txt | curl -Fblah=\<- localhost:2222
```

We see this in the `socat` output:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="blah"
msg: hello curl
```

If we change the string from `blah` to a `-` we'll see the following:

```
$ cat ~/hello.txt | curl -F-=\<- localhost:2222
```

Result:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="-"
```

So as we can see, the argument after the initial `-F` is the name of the form we want to submit against. The man page for `curl mentions that`-F` is for submitting a HTTP form where we want to specify the name:

```
 -F, --form <name=content>
   (HTTP)  This  lets  curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user
   has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using
   the Content-Type  multipart/form-data  according  to  RFC  2388.
   This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content'
   part to be a file,  prefix  the  file  name with  an  @  sign.
   To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file
   name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then
   that @ makes a file  get  attached  in  the  post as a file upload,
   while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that
   text field from a file.
```

The rest of the switches to the `-F-=` switch are connecting the STDIN input to this argument. `<-`. STDIN will contain a stream of the content coming in via the `cat file |`.

#### Comparing args - `'-F-=<-'` vs. `-F-=\<-`

These 2 notations are identical. Again we can use additional verbosity to see what's happening.

```
$ set -x; cat ~/hello.txt | curl '-F-=<-' localhost:2222; set +x
...
+ cat /Users/smingolelli/hello.txt
+ curl '-F-=<-' localhost:2222
```

Whereas the other method:

```
$ set -x; cat ~/hello.txt | curl -F-=\<- localhost:2222; set +x
...
+ cat /Users/smingolelli/hello.txt
+ curl '-F-=<-' localhost:2222
```

People like to use the first method because it saves them an extra character in typing it. But from `curl`'s perspective, they're identical. All that `-F-=\<-` is doing is escaping the redirect so that `curl` gets to see it instead of the shell processing it.

---

#### Original Quesiton

The original question asked about this:

```
$ echo foo | curl -d 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us
```

To which I answered:

When you use the switch `-d` to curl you're implying a POST, from the `curl` man page.

```
-d/--data <data>
     (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, 
     in the same way that a browser does  when  a user has filled in an 
     HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass 
     the data to the server using the content-type 
     application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Compare to -F/--form.
```